# Кириллица в строках С++

Tags: строки, c++, linux

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. В программе на С++ под Linux нужно поочередно открывать текстовые файлы, имя которых начинается на букву кириллицы, а заканчивается латиницей. Ну, например, сначала ю.txt, а потом л.txt. Но, поскольку, русская буква занимает 2 байта, то возникает проблема  с совмещением ее в одной строке с латинскими, которые весят по 1 байту. Вариант создать строку с одновременной инициализацие, например
 `char word[] = "ю.txt"`
работает. Но таких файло у меня больше 30. И объявить столько переменных не считаю целесообразным. Поэтому в цикле поочередно меняю word[0] на нужную русскую букву. И вот тут как раз все и рушится. Потому что на место одной русской буквы другая русская корректно не записывается.

Comment: А исходник есть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запишите все русские буквы в одну строку

```
char *b="абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
```

и копируйте из этого массива

```
memcpy(word, b+i*2, 2);
```

Другой вариант - смотрите как устроена utf-8:

```
$ od -t x1
абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя
0000000 d0 b0 d0 b1 d0 b2 d0 b3 d0 b4 d0 b5 d1 91 d0 b6
0000020 d0 b7 d0 b8 d0 b9 d0 ba d0 bb d0 bc d0 bd d0 be
0000040 d0 bf d1 80 d1 81 d1 82 d1 83 d1 84 d1 85 d1 86
0000060 d1 87 d1 88 d1 89 d1 8a d1 8b d1 8c d1 8d d1 8e
0000100 d1 8f 0a
```

Первый байт - старший, он увеличивается когда второй должен бы достигнуть значения 0xc0